# Linux: date cmd doesn't accept its own output string as input string?

Tags: linux, date, input

```
$ date
Mi 14. Jun 09:54:58 CEST 2017

$ date -d "Mi 14. Jun 09:54:58 CEST 2017" +%s
date: invalid date ‘Mi 14. Jun 09:54:58 CEST 2017’
```

Why wouldn't the date command accept its own output string as valid input string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`info date` told me that `-d` option requires input in locale independent format. To get the *output* in such a format, use:

```
LC_TIME=C date
```

So the following should work:

```
date -d "$(LC_TIME=C date)" +%s
```

It's only a cumbersome example that has a little sense (compare `date +%s`) but it shows that `date` accepts its output as an input.

---

Trivia: To make most commands produce locale independent output, use `LANG=C some_command`. In the above example `LANG=C date` should work as well.