# Formatting date in bash script issue

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to take the date a file was created and format the date in a bash script. First I run:

```
filedate=(ls -ltr |awk '{print $6,$7}' |tail -n 1 )
```

This command is to save just the date of the file as a variable. Next I want to run the date command to format the date in the way that I need. The issue is that the 'date' command requires the date to be in quotation marks. So i run  :

```
formatedate=$(date -d \" $filedate \"  +%Y%m%d )
```

This keeps giving me an error usually print something like "date: extra operand '4' " or " date: extra operand '"'   "

Comment: Why do you think the date command requires the date to be in quotation marks?

Comment: If i try to command with no quotes like : "date -d Mar 3 +%Y%m%d" it gives an error "date:extra operand '+%Y%m%d , but if I put Mar 3 in double or single quotes the command executes as I intend it too

Comment: The quotes are removed by the shell before passing the argument to `date`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So many issues…

`date` does not need double-quotes. [The shell needs them](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).

```
formatedate=$(date -d "$filedate" +%Y%m%d)
```

But `date -d` [may not understand what `$filedate` expands to](https://superuser.com/a/1219102/432690). In general you need `LC_TIME=C ls …` in the first place.

But [you shouldn't parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) in the zeroth place, at least not without `--quoting-style=shell-always` (which may or may not be supported by your `ls`) to get filename(s) (not date(s)).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38996701/10765659) provides reliable ways to identify the most recent file in the current working directory (it seems this is what you're trying to do). After you get the filename, use `stat` to get the date you need, preferably as seconds since Epoch. *Then* use `date -d`.

```bsh
# in Bash, GNU ls required

eval "files=($(ls -t --quoting-style=shell-always))"
if ((${#files[@]} > 0)); then
   filedate="$(stat -c %Y "${files[0]}")"
   formatedate="$(date -d "@$filedate" +%Y%m%d)"
   echo "$formatedate"
fi
```

Note `ls --quoting-style=` is not portable, `stat` is not portable, `date -d` is not portable. Hopefully you can use them.

Comment: Awesome this worked perfectly. Thanks once again Kamil